# In angularJS, what causes a page reload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have AngularJS setup to have routes and I have templates that hide/show based on the route (which looks like "/#/admin/overview"). For some reason though the entire page/controller is reloading every time I change the tab I am looking at, even though I am using ng-show and routes that only work for a client side app. What am I doing wrong?

Additional information can be found at [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161145/angularjs-page-reloads-when-changing-route), but I couldn't get any responses.

Thank you for your time and patience in reading this.